# Nest JS Schema for Relationship of documents (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm working on simple quiz app using **Nest JS** and **MongoDB**. I have 2 collections like (Questions & Tests)

Questions Collection Structure:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "605af6afb506557d26b3d6ce"
    },
    "options": ["2018", "2019", "2020", "2021"],
    "title": "what is the current year?",
    "answer": "3",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Tests Collection Structure:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "605afc98b7821c06d46419f1"
    },
    "questions": ["605af6afb506557d26b3d6ce", "605af6deb506557d26b3d6cf", "605af6f0b506557d26b3d6d0", "605af711b506557d26b3d6d1"],
    "title": "Demo Test",
    "description": "This is demo test",
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2021-03-24T08:47:20.071Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Now When the **Tests** are fetch, I want to return question detail as well. Please let me know if there is any option to make some relationship or reference between collections using **NEST JS**.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB are an not relational DB Engine so you can give relational data by default. A way is query an entity, get the id for the relation and query the another entity using the id.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how your squema design looks like, You can use the populate method.

```
const tests = await this.testModel.findById(id).populate('questions');
```

if you want to select certain fields:

```
const tests = await this.testModel.findById(id).populate({ path: 'questions', select: '_id title' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep reference of Question in Test schema for relating both question and test db.
Tests Collection Schema be like:

```js
    import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
    @Schema()
    export class Test {
      @Prop([{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }])
      question: Question[];
    
      @Prop()
      title: string;
    
      @Prop()
      description: string;
    }
```

As a test may have more than one question so here question type is list [], otherwise it will be an object {}
check more clear view here this [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb)